# RadioButtonFor doesn't call onchange after load the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

not sure the title makes sense, but I have the code bellow to hide/show some fields when we select a yes/no radiobutton

```
<div class="container" style="width:100%;margin-top:2%">
@if (Model != null)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("NextButton_Click", "Questionnaire", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.QuestionsPaging.Count(); i++)
                {
                    ...
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p>
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(n => n.QuestionsAnswers[index].HasAnswer, false, new { @radioIndex = i, @onchange = "CallChangefunc(this)" }) @Html.Label("No")
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(n => n.QuestionsAnswers[index].HasAnswer, true, new { @radioIndex = i, @onchange = "CallChangefunc(this)" }) @Html.Label("Yes")
                            </p>
                            <div id="div_questions_@i" style="display:none">
                                ...
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function CallChangefunc(myRadioButton) {
        var divName = "div_questions_" + myRadioButton.getAttribute("radioIndex");
        var divElement = document.getElementById(divName);

        if ($(myRadioButton).val().toLowerCase() === "true") {
            if (divElement.style.display != 'inline') {
                divElement.style.display = 'inline';
            }
        } else {
            if (divElement.style.display != 'none') {
                divElement.style.display = 'none'
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The code works fine, I click the radiobutton and it hides/shows the divs as expected. The problem I'm having is that when I load the form it selects the RadioButton as expected but the event 'onchange' doesn't get triggered, so I have all fields hidden even with some radiobuttons set to yes.

I don't have too much experience in web, not sure how can I fix it, I've tried some stuffs but didn't work, any help is welcome.

Thank you.

---

**Solution**: Thanks @jom

I added " $(':radio[id^="QuestionsAnswers"]').trigger('change');" and checked if the radiobutton is checked, because ".trigger('change')" trigger the event for every radiobutton, now I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(':radio[id^="QuestionsAnswers"]').trigger('change');
    });

    function CallChangefunc(myRadioButton) {
        var divName = "div_questions_" + myRadioButton.getAttribute("radioIndex");
        var divElement = document.getElementById(divName);

        if ($(myRadioButton).val().toLowerCase() === "true" && myRadioButton.checked) {
            if (divElement.style.display != 'inline') {
                divElement.style.display = 'inline';
            }
        } else if ($(myRadioButton).val().toLowerCase() === "false" && myRadioButton.checked) {
            if (divElement.style.display != 'none') {
                divElement.style.display = 'none'
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Check the console for errors.

Comment: what did you mean by "when I load the form" ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no errors on console, I tried to put 'alert' inside the event, it doesn't get triggered

Comment: @MustaphaLarhrouch first time I load the page

Comment: the event gets triggered just when I click the RadioButton

Comment: Is there other code attached to the radios? Something which causes a page unload?

Comment: Did you try doing `.trigger('change')` on the radio buttons?

Comment: your function is called on change. when you reload the form it doesn't change so the function doesnt trigger

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no, just the code I posted

Comment: @jom where should I call it?

Comment: @Matt.S but when I load the page for the first time and set the value from the DB, I think it should trigger onchange, again, I'm learning how web works

Comment: when you reload the page the change has allready been made. you could just check on reloading which radio button is checked and run your function according to the outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this on either `$(document).ready` or before the closing `</body>` tag.

```
  $(':radio[id^="QuestionsAnswers"]').trigger('change');

  // Or attach the handlers by script instead of going through Razor engine

  $(':radio[id^="QuestionsAnswers"]').change(function () {
    CallChangefunc(this);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `$(document).ready` before  `function CallChangefunc(myRadioButton)`